# Grails not executing on IntelliJ (NoClassDefFoundError)

Tags: grails, intellij-idea, classpath

I have upgraded my application from grails 1.2.2 to 1.3.1-RC1. While things seem to work when executing grails from command prompt, I cannot make it run from my IDE IntelliJ (last development version).

The error I got straightaway is:

```
Error executing script RunApp: net/sf/json/JSONException 
... 
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sf.json.JSONException
```

Adding the library `json-lib.jar` to the modules dependencies does not change anything in IntelliJ.

Also, it seems that there are 2 JSONException classes defined in 2 different packages :

- `org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.json` in `grails.jar`
- another package `net.sf.json` in *json-lib-2.3-jdk15.jar* located in lib folder of cloud-foundry plugin

Do you have any idea about what's happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case, someone encountered the same problem, I finally managed to solve the issue without being sure what was the real fix.

In any case, my problem happened after I have upgraded my Grails from 1.2 to 1.3 and I had old libraries attached to plugins. What I did is:

Project Settings -> Modules -> irofoot-grailsPlugins -> Dependencies -> Grails User Library -> Edit -> Detach old libraries (with Grails-1.2 path)

and then it worked (no more ClassNotFoundException)!!